# Laravel5.2: Send Queue Emails by user timezone?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, timezone, queue

I want to send emails by user timezone using Queues, I have `timezone` column in users table.

Currently, what I am doing is using laravel mutator to set time to UTC before saving to DB:

```
public function setSendOnAttribute($value){
    if( $value )
        $this->attributes['send_on'] = Carbon::parse($value, auth()->user()->timezone)->tz(config('app.timezone'));//date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value));
}
```

above code is not working, As user can use application from anywhere in the world & email must shot by user's timezone.

Please guide me, what I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Kaleem

Comment: You are setting the attribute as a Carbon instance, your model is setted to parse this into date or datetime to store in your database?

Comment: `$mail->send_on = $request['send_on'] ? $request['send_on'] : Carbon::now();` this is what in Controller file

Comment: When usign Carbon, you need to get the data from your instance in the propper format to store in your database, or to use in your view. To do that, check this:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting